ScaleLine and measurement value is not matching in OpenLayers 10
I'm creating a map with EPSG:4326 project and I have added Scaleline as follows

const scaleControl = new ScaleLine({
  units: 'metric',
  bar: true,
  steps: 4,
  dpi: 96,
  text: true,
  minWidth: 140,
});

and my getLength function looks like this
  const length = getLength(line, {"projection": 'EPSG:4326', "radius" : '6371008.8'});

but still there is a difference in length and scale 
what might be the solution to this ?

That is to be expected with EPSG:4326.  It is a non-conformal projection which has different scales for X and Y axes (except at the equator).  The ScaleLine shows the average of those.  If it was correct for one axis it would be wrong for the other.

Does this mean that this kind of issue will not appear for meter based projections ?

Over short distances most other projections will not have this issue.  All projections have some distortion (e.g. Greenland is much smaller than Africa but polar regions are often distorted).
